# How to release the a lock on Apex Class from Scheduled Job

Tags: managed-package, scheduled-apex, beta-managed-package

Is there a way to release a "lock" on an Apex class after the scheduled job that was using that class has been deleted?

For some reason, this "lock" is still active and is preventing me from uninstalling a managed package that this Apex class is a part of.

Comment: What error message are you getting? Not the 'Class has scheduled jobs pending' message, I assume? So the scheduled job has been deleted but when you try to uninstall the managed package that included the schedulable class, it prevents you from uninstalling? Please post the precise error message. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a Known Issue regarding getting rid of the code lock from Scheduling: http://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000STwPAAW . See if this is your situation.